# Can the property @JSONIgnore be set on a per call basis?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am working on a site that uses promo codes to potentially provide users free memberships to the site.  The level that a member signs up at is an attribute of a promo code object and stored in the database as an int, either 1 or 2.  However, the only time the member level attribute is relevant to the UI of the site is for a landing page associated with a specific promo code.  So for that case, I don't want the member level to be ignored by JSON.  After a user returns to the site and has a promo code object associated with their account, we no longer care about their member level so I would like the member level attribute to be ignored by JSON.

So my question is this, is it possible to set an object's attribute to `@JSONIgnore` on a per access basis, or can an attribute only be ignored or not ignored?  In other words is there a method like `object.getAttribute().setAttributeJSONIgnore(true | false)`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232045/serialization-and-deserialization-with-jackson-how-to-programmatically-ignore-f/11233190#11233190. you can't selectively turn `@JsonIgnore` on/off at runtime.

Comment: I think this question indicates the application business logic is being put in the wrong place.  I recommend letting the data serialization/deserialization (transport) layer be as dumb as possible, and putting business logic where folks would expect it to be, where it would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Annotation-based approaches are static, since although you could use custom `AnnotationIntrospector`, resulting `JsonSerializer` instances are reused since their construction is costly.

But there are ways to filter out properties, check out "[Filtering Properties](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html)" article, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar with JSONViews (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews).

You'd create a Base View and then extend it with a PromoPage View.  In the object you're serializing, you'd add the annotation to each property. So the ones you want to appear every time would be

```
@JsonView(Views.Base.class) 
String name;
```

The properties you only wanted to show on those certain Promo Pages would be something like

```
@JsonView(Views.PromoPage.class) 
Integer memberLevel;
```

Then if you have different JAX-RS methods for getting the promopages than the other landing page, you can annotate the methods with the appropriate View like so

```
  @JsonView(Views.Base.class)
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
  public Object getNormalLandingPageInfo() {
    ...
  }

  @JsonView(Views.PromoPage.class)
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
  public Object getPromoLandingPageInfo() {
    ...
  }
```

If you don't, in your logic, you can do whatever you want to determine when to show the PromoPage View, then do something like this

```
if (showPromoPage)
    objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, object, Views.PromoPage.class);
else
    objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, object, Views.Base.class);
```