# How to ignore a specific property when deserializing a JSON object?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am working against a existing REST interface. One of the incoming JSON objects contains a property called `size` which I would like to ignore when deserializing this JSON object?

My standard behavior is to fail on unknown property, so I cannot configure the used object mapper to ignore unknown properties.

Comment: Probably look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232045/serialization-and-deserialization-with-jackson-how-to-programmatically-ignore-f) !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties("size")` to your POJO. See the JavaDoc for `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at [fasterxml.github.io](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) for more information.

Comment: Or, generally: @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Comment: @MichałZiober: Since the question states "… I cannot configure the used object mapper to ignore unknown properties." I opted for the specific version, but you are certainly right.

Comment: I know, but I wanted to show another possibility. Your answer is correct and should be used first.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to ignore property ONLY by deserialization, but still serialize it (read-only), it is possible with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value={ "size" }, allowGetters= true)`.

More info here: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#allowGetters()