# What's the common way to deal with Jackson serialization

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

Currently I have a project that makes use of Spring-Hibernate and also Jackson to deal with JSON. The first time I tried to use Jackson I always got `LazyInitializationException` and sometimes infinite loop for multiple entities that references each other. Then I found `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

Now the problem is sometimes it is needed to ignore properties but sometimes I just need those properties to be serializable. Is there a way to sometimes ignore several fields and sometimes serialize the fields at the runtime?

I found "[Serialization and Deserialization with Jackson: how to programmatically ignore fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232045/serialization-and-deserialization-with-jackson-how-to-programmatically-ignore-f)"

But if I always have to use the mix in annotation, it would be cumbersome if an object dozens of properties to retrieve. Eg. In page1 I need `propertyA`, `propertyB`, `propertyC`; in page2 I need `propertyA` and `propertyC`; in page3 I only need `propertyB`. In those cases alone I would have to create 1 class for each page resulting in 3 classes.

So in that case is there a way to define something like:

```
objectA.ignoreAllExcept('propertyA');
String[] properties = {'propertyA', 'propertyC'};
objectB.ignoreAllExcept(properties); // Retrieve propertyA and propertyC
objectC.ignore(properties);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is a [Module](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.html). The documentation says that [Modules](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) are

> Simple interface for extensions that can be registered with [ObjectMappers](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to provide a well-defined set of extensions to default functionality.

Following is am example of how you might use them to accomplish what you want. Note, there are other ways using which this can be achieved; this is just one of them.

A simple DTO that can be used for specifying the properties to filter:

```
public class PropertyFilter {

    public Class<?> classToFilter;
    public Set<String> propertiesToIgnore = Collections.emptySet();

    public PropertyFilter(Class<?> classToFilter, Set<String> propertiesToIgnore) {
        this.classToFilter = classToFilter;
        this.propertiesToIgnore = propertiesToIgnore;
    }
}
```

A custom module that filters out properties based on some `attribute` that you store in the current `request`.

```
public class MyModule extends Module {

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return "Test Module";
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new MySerializerModifier());
    }

    @Override
    public Version version() {
        // Modify if you need to.
        return Version.unknownVersion();
    }

    public static class MySerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

        public BeanSerializerBuilder updateBuilder(SerializationConfig config,
                BeanDescription beanDesc,
                BeanSerializerBuilder builder) {
            List<PropertyFilter> filters =  (List<PropertyFilter>) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getAttribute("filters", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
            PropertyFilter filter = getPropertyFilterForClass(filters, beanDesc.getBeanClass());
            if(filter == null) {
                return builder;
            }

            List<BeanPropertyWriter> propsToWrite = new ArrayList<BeanPropertyWriter>();
            for(BeanPropertyWriter writer : builder.getProperties()) {
                if(!filter.propertiesToIgnore.contains(writer.getName())) {
                    propsToWrite.add(writer);
                }
            }
            builder.setProperties(propsToWrite);
            return builder;
        }


        private PropertyFilter getPropertyFilterForClass(List<PropertyFilter> filters, Class<?> classToCheck) {
            for(PropertyFilter f : filters) {
                if(f.classToFilter.equals(classToCheck)) {
                    return f;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Note: There is a `changeProperties` method in the [BeanSerializerModifier](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.html) class that is more appropriate for changing the property list (according to the documentation). So you can move the code written in the `updateBuilder` to `changeProperties` method with appropriate changes.

Now, you need to register this custom `module` with your [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). You can get the Jackson HTTP message converter from your application context, and get its object mapper. I am assuming you already know how to do that as you have been dealing with the lazy-initialization issue as well.

```
// Figure out a way to get the ObjectMapper.
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = ... // get the jackson-mapper;
converter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new MyModule())
```

And you are done. When you want to customize the serialization for a particular type of object, create a `PropertyFilter` for that, put it in a `List` and make it available as an attribute in the current request. This is just a simple example. You might need to tweak it a bit to suit your needs.

In your question, you seem to be looking for a way to specify the properties-to-filter-out on the serialized objects themselves. That, in my opinion, should be avoided as the list of properties to filter-out doesn't belong to your entities. However, if you do want to do that, create an `interface` that provides `setters` and `getters` for the list of properties. Suppose the name of the interface is `CustomSerialized` Then, you can modify the `MyModule` class to look for the instances of this `CustomSerialized` interface and filter out the properties accordingly.

Note: You might need to adjust/tweak a few things based on the versions of the libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a more flexible way to do it. You can configure Jackson in a such a way that it will silently ignore lazy loaded properties instead of stopping serialization process. So you can reuse the same class. Just load all necessary properties / relations and pass it to Jackson. You can try to do it by declaring your custom `ObjectMapper` and by turning off `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` feature. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out properties without modifying classes by creating a static interface for a mixin annotation. Next, annotate that interface with the @JsonFilter annotation. Create a SimpleBeanPropertyFilter and a SimpleFilterProvider. Then create an ObjectWriter with your filter provider by invoking objectMapper.writer(filterProvider)